# Remove view 1 after replaced by view2

Tags: iphone, ios, selector

I have a small code to display image 1 and after 2 seconds replace image1 by image2 with animation below

```
UIImageView *view1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 410, 1020, 400)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpeg"];
view1.image = image;
[self.view addSubview:view1];
UIImageView *view2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init ];
view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 0, 400);
view2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bien.jpeg"];
[self.view addSubview:view2];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeView: view1:)];
view2.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 410, 800, 400);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and function removeView to remove view1 from superview below:

```
-(void)removeView: (UIImageView *)view1{
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

So i dont know why my function to remove view1 from superview not work, please help me! Thanks alot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use block based animations (available since iOS 4).
They are much easier to use and don't need to send parameters through methods and all that stuff.
Example:

```
UIImageView *view1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
//initialize your UIImageView view1
[self.view addSubview:view1];
UIImageView *view2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
//initialize your UIImageView view2
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    //here happens the animation
    [self addSubview:view2];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //here happens stuff when animation is complete
    [view1 removeFromSuperView];
}];
```

Remember to vote up and or mark as accepted answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, this solution is the best for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The selector cannot pass the parameter. Modify your method to

```
-(void)removeView{
   [view1 removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

where "view1" is a instance to your view.

and your selector to:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeView)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code!!

```
UIImageView *view1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 410, 1020, 400)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpeg"];
view1.tag = 1;
view1.image = image;
[self.view addSubview:view1];

UIImageView *view2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init ];
view2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 0, 400);
view2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bien.jpeg"];
[self.view addSubview:view2];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeView: view1:)];
view2.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 410, 800, 400);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

// Remove View Method

```
-(void)removeView : (UIImageView *) imgVew {

    if (imgVew.tag == 1)

        [imgVew removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Access it -

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeView:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is simple, this selector is **not** exists in your class: `-removeView:view1:`. thus there is nothing to call back after the animation finished. this is why your `-(void)removeView:(UIImageView *)view1;` method will be never called back.

please, realised your real selector is `-removeView:` and it is not equal with `-removeView:view1:`

if you want to pass parameter through the `didStopSelector`, I would have a bad news: you **cannot** do it as you did in your code, so this part is wrong at all:

```
// WRONG AT ALL:    
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeView:view1:)];

// PROPER WAY:
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
```

because the `didStopSelector` must be the following kind of selector with the following parameters.

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context;
```

you **can** pass parameter for your callback method like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:view1]; // see the context's value
```

and in your `didStopSelector` you can use it somehow like:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    [((UIView *)context) removeFromSuperView];
}
```